# Painfully slow MySql query when joining two tables on primary/foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing, query-optimization

We use the Ahoy ruby library for tracking user visits and events. In order to provide feedback to users, we periodically run counts on certain events and visits.

The two tables are relatively large, but not huge. Visits is 6MM+ rows and Events are 23MM+ rows.

Below is a sample query, which takes 80s to run:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `ahoy_events` 
INNER JOIN `visits`  ON `visits`.`id` = `ahoy_events`.`visit_id` 
WHERE `ahoy_events`.`event_target_id` = 8471 
  AND `ahoy_events`.`event_target_type` = 'Project' 
  AND visits.entity_id = 668 
  AND (`visits`.`user_type` IS NULL OR `visits`.`user_type` = 'User')
```

And here is the explain for that query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: visits
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,index_visits_on_entity_id,index_visits_on_entity_id_and_user_type,index_visits_on_entity_id_and_started_at,index_visits_on_entity_id_and_user_id_and_user_type,index_visits_on_entity_id_user_id_user_type_started_at
          key: index_visits_on_entity_id_user_id_user_type_started_at
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 1567140
     filtered: 19.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ahoy_events
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_ahoy_events_on_visit_id,index_ahoy_events_on_event_target_id_and_event_target_type
          key: index_ahoy_events_on_visit_id
      key_len: 17
          ref: givecorpssite.visits.id
         rows: 2
     filtered: 11.47
        Extra: Using where
```

When I run just a count on the individual tables, each runs in 200ms to 600ms, i.e:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `ahoy_events` WHERE `ahoy_events`.`event_target_id` = 8471 AND `ahoy_events`.`event_target_type` = 'Project'
```

and

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `visits` where visits.entity_id = 668 AND (`visits`.`user_type` IS NULL OR `visits`.`user_type` = 'Donor')
```

But joining them on the primary/foreign key, causes the query to take 80s+

BTW, the keys (visit_id, and the id column on visits) are UUIDs and are BINARY(16) columns.

Am I wrong to believe this query should not be so slow?

Comment: I wouldn't automatically assume it is the JOIN on indexed fields; `OR` can cause performance issues. Just to check, try the query without the `visits.user_type IS NULL` condition. _Also, last I checked, MySQL has rather abysmal support for UUIDs, so you may be basically comparing indexes on CHAR(32) values._

Comment: Interesting @Uueerdo, taking out the Null check, the query responded in 3 seconds. Taking out the check for User and leaving the check for Null, it took 108s. But the numbers aren't equal either. As there were about 3800 rows with 'User', and 1MM+ with Null, so perhaps not surprising that the Null check would take so much longer.

Comment: Would it improve matters if the user_type field had a default value, like "unknown" instead of the Null value?

Comment: It is unlikely, as it is probably not the null check (null check should be faster than a string comparison), but the presence of the `OR`ed conditions or increased results being dealt with. I'll add another option as a possible answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is unclear exactly whether the OR selection condition is causing an issue, and you are not really seeking row-level data in your results, you could instead try conditional aggregation of this sort:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(`visits`.`user_type` IS NULL OR `visits`.`user_type` = 'User',1,NULL) 
FROM `ahoy_events` 
INNER JOIN `visits`  ON `visits`.`id` = `ahoy_events`.`visit_id` 
WHERE `ahoy_events`.`event_target_id` = 8471 
  AND `ahoy_events`.`event_target_type` = 'Project' 
  AND visits.entity_id = 668 
;
```

`COUNT` ignores null values; alternatively,
`SUM(IF(visits.user_type IS NULL OR visits.user_type = 'User',1,0))` is a little clearer and gets the same result (though it could in theory be a little more costly performance-wise).

In this query, you'll be processing more rows without the condition reducing them, but it can end up "cheaper" to scan the larger results, than scan the table for a smaller set of results.

Comment: This is much better. The first time I ran it, it took 20s. The second time, 7s. So a big improvement. Still slow for what I would think is a simple query that is well indexed. So perhaps the UUID's are an issue.

Comment: I wouldn't use the second run's execution time as a barometer unless you changed the values queried; MySQL can cache results. ...though I would expect an even faster followup query if that were happening; the second execution likely benefited from the disk or table being cached (rather than the results).

Comment: And even shorter:  `SUM(visits.user_type IS NULL OR visits.user_type = 'User')`  (A boolean is treated as 0 or 1.)

Answer (score 0):

Coverings Indexes:

```
visits:  INDEX(entity_id, user_type, id)  -- in this order
ahoy_events:  INDEX(event_target_id, event_target_type, visit_id)
```

By being covering, there may be less I/O.  (I/O is the slowest part of a query.)

There is some chance that the following will run faster:

```
SELECT  
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `ahoy_events` AS e
            INNER JOIN  `visits` AS v  ON v.`id` = e.`visit_id`
            WHERE  e.`event_target_id` = 8471
              AND  e.`event_target_type` = 'Project'
              AND  visits.entity_id = 668
              AND  v.`user_type` IS NULL 
    ) + 
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  `ahoy_events` AS e
            INNER JOIN  `visits` AS v  ON v.`id` = e.`visit_id`
            WHERE  e.`event_target_id` = 8471
              AND  e.`event_target_type` = 'Project'
              AND  visits.entity_id = 668
              AND  v.`user_type` = 'User' 
    );
```

It needs the same indexes I suggested above.

The rationale here is to avoid the `OR`.  (Indexes usually cannot be used with `OR`.)

If you want to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Thank you Rick. Are you looking for the `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` for the two tables in question? Also, which query are you looking for the EXPLAIN. Do you want this after I add the indexes and then run the EXPLAIN on your suggested query?

Comment: Preferably the `CREATEs` for any tables involved and the `EXPLAIN` after adding the indexes.